# Execute PL/SQL with oracledb won't take affect

Tags: oracle, plsql

given the below PL/SQL statement:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE special';
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
    END;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE special(
        id int DEFAULT NULL,
        col1 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        " Name " varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        specchar varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
    )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ADMIN.special VALUES (1, ''Customer Name'', ''MOL'', ''normal'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ADMIN.special VALUES (2, ''Customer Name'', ''INA'', ''[blockq] text'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ADMIN.special VALUES (3, ''Customer Name'', ''LUKOIL'', ''"quoted" text1'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ADMIN.special VALUES (4, ''Customer Code'', ''ABC'', ''questionmark ?'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ADMIN.special VALUES (5, ''Customer Code'', ''CDE'', ''back\slash'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ADMIN.special VALUES (6, ''Customer Code'', ''FGH'', ''hej   haj'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ADMIN.special VALUES (100, ''Customer Code'', ''F\x00apple'', ''hej  haj'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ADMIN.special VALUES (101, ''Customer Code'', ''F\x7Fapple'', ''hej  haj'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ADMIN.special VALUES (102, ''Customer Code'', ''F\rapp\nle'', ''hej  ha'')';
END;
```

This should re-create and populate a simple test table in OCI (I suppose, behave same as on-premise PL/SQL database)

The below code read the statement from a file and try to execute it:

```
    with oracledb.connect(user=auth["username"], password=auth["password"], dsn=dsn) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(file.read())
```

After executing this statement and when I go to the OCI database console (browser), a select statement from this table won't result any rows.

Issuing this query from the web console will populate the table.

Can anybody help me, what did I wrong?

Comment: I won't say there is *never* a case when creating a table on the fly and loading it statically (and hence using execute immediate in order to get it to compile without missing dependencies) is appropriate, but those situations are extremely rare. You should think carefully about why this approach was taken, and if at all possible prefer instead a permanent table and normal insert statements (without using execute immediate). If this is intended to be a temporary scratch table reused each session, consider using a "global temporary table" instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to issue a commit after inserting the records. Try adding `conn.commit()` after cursor.execute

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [tylert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77754085/1509264):

Un`COMMIT`ted data is only visible within the session that created it (and will `ROLLBACK` at the end of the session if it has not been `COMMIT`ted). If you can't see the data from another session (i.e. in the OCI database console) then make sure you have issued a `COMMIT` command in the session where you `INSERT`ed the data (i.e. either at the end of the PL/SQL block or within your Python code).

*Note: even if you connect as the same user, this will create a separate session and you will not be able to see the uncommitted data in the other session.*

From the [`COMMIT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COMMIT.html#GUID-6CD5C9A7-54B9-4FA2-BA3C-D6B4492B9EE2):

> Until you commit a transaction:
>
> - You can see any changes you have made during the transaction by querying the modified tables, but other users cannot see the changes. After you commit the transaction, the changes are visible to other users' statements that execute after the commit.
> - You can roll back (undo) any changes made during the transaction with the `ROLLBACK` statement (see `ROLLBACK`).